# Is $r \in \text{Rad}(A)$?

Tags: spectral-theory, banach-algebras

Let $u$ be an element of a Banach algebra $A$ such that $u^2-u \in \text{Rad}(A)$.
I am trying to show that there exists a projection in $A$ which is equal to $u$ modulo the radical.

We have that $\sigma(u^2-u)=\{0\}$ and by the spectral mapping theorem we can show $\sigma(u)=\{0,1\}$.

Let $U=B(0,\frac{1}{4})$ and $V=B(1,\frac{1}{4})$ then $U$ and $V$ are two disjoint open sets which contains $0$ and $1$ respectively.
Therefore $\sigma(u)\subset U\cup V$ with $U\cap V = \emptyset$. Now let $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ be two closed curves surrounding $0$ and $1$, contained within $U$ and $V$ respectively.
Then $\Gamma=\Gamma_1\cup \Gamma_2$ encloses the spectrum and is contained within an open set surrounding the spectrum.
Let $f:U\cup V \to \mathbb{C}$ be defined by
$$
f(\lambda)=\begin{cases}
1, & \lambda \in V \\
0, & \lambda \in U 
\end{cases}.
$$
Then $f$ is analytic on $U\cup V$.
By the holomorphic functional calculus, we have that
$$f(u)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\Gamma f(\lambda)(u-\lambda \textbf{1})^{-1}d\lambda,$$
which is a projection in $A$.

Let $h(\lambda)= \lambda - f(\lambda)$, then using a similar argument, we can define $r=h(u)$.

Then we have that $$u=f(u) + (u-f(u))= f(u) + h(u) = f(u)+r.$$

Do we have that $r \in \text{Rad}(A)$?

If so, then the result will be proven, but I am having some difficulty seeing whether or not $r \in \text{Rad}(A)$ is true.

I do know that $r$ is quasinilpotent, since it has zero spectrum. But I am not sure how to show that $r \in \text{Rad}(A)$.

Comment: What is your definition of the radical?

Comment: @Ruy , in this case, the Jacobson Radical

Comment: Is $A$ commutative?

Comment: @Ruy, no assumptions are made on commutativity no. $A$ is also not assumed to be semi-simple (as then the result is trivial), and if $A$ is commutative, then the radical coincides with the quasinilpotents, in which case it is then proven. So I am not assuming $A$ is commutative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$h(\lambda )= \lambda ^2-\lambda $, and
$$
  g(\lambda ) = \left\{\matrix{
  \displaystyle {1}/({1-\lambda }) & \text{, if }  \lambda \in U. \cr
  \displaystyle {1}/{\lambda } & \text{, if }  \lambda \in V,
  }
  \right.
  $$
and notice that
$\lambda -f(\lambda ) = g(\lambda )h(\lambda )$.  Therefore
$$
  r = u -f(u) = g(u)h(u) = g(u)(u^2-u),
  $$
which lies in the radical because $u^2-u$ does and the radical is an ideal.

Comment: This was exactly the type of argument I was hoping for.. Thank you very much!